# Managing the drop of information when converting/downsampling from vector to raster (QGIS/GDAL)

Tags: rasterization, resolution

I need to rasterize my vector (polygon) data to 10m resolution (to match Sentinel's 10m resolution). But as you can see in the picture, the results are bad for small structures like roads etc. Is there a way or trick to solve this to make it look a bit better (connected roads), more like in the left picture (but with 10m resolution to match the Sentinel data)?

[image: rasterised vector data with different resolutions]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/427625/edit) to specify the software you use to rasterize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gdal_rasterize`, enable the [ALL_TOUCHED rasterization option](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-at) by adding the `-at` flag to your command.

If you are using QGIS, enable the [ALL_TOUCHED rasterization option](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-at) by adding the `-at` flag in the "Additional command-line parameters" of the rasterize tool.

[image]

Without `-at`:
[image]

With `-at`:
[image]

Comment: thank you. "-at" makes it look better, but still not good. i think it is because I have dense annotations (compared to your sparse example). If I only rasterize the road I get the same results as you do. So i can probably make a workaround by burning in the roads as a last step in the raster. thank you!

Comment: Your question specifically asked about roads, not annotations